# Evaluate $\cos \frac\pi7\cos \frac{3\pi}7\cos\frac{9\pi}7 $

Tags: trigonometry

I need help evaluating the expression

$$\cos \frac\pi7\cos \frac{3\pi}7\cos\frac{9\pi}7 $$

Can someone show the steps he or she used to arrive at the answer?

Comment: As well as [this one that also comes with a geometric proof](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/pythagoras/CosCosCos.shtml)

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2139075/prove-that-cos-pi-7-is-root-of-equation-8x3-4x2-4x1-0

Comment: It's well known that $\cos(\pi/7)\cos(2\pi/7)\cos(3\pi /7)=1/8$; how does that help you?


https://mathworld.wolfram.com/TrigonometryAnglesPi7.html

Comment: $-\cos(x)\cos(2x)\cos(3x)$ where $x=\dfrac{\pi}{7}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note

\begin{align}
& \cos \frac\pi7\cos \frac{3\pi}7\cos\frac{9\pi}7\\
= &-\cos \frac{8\pi}7\cos \frac{4\pi}7\cos\frac{2\pi}7\\
=& -\cos \frac{8\pi}7\cos \frac{4\pi}7\sin\frac{4\pi}7\cdot\frac1{2\sin\frac{2\pi}7}\\
 =& -\cos \frac{8\pi}7\sin\frac{8\pi}7\cdot\frac1{4\sin\frac{2\pi}7}\\
=& -\frac{\sin\frac{16\pi}7}{8\sin\frac{2\pi}7}=-\frac18
\end{align}